# NPM crashed by trying to install a package and use --save flag

Tags: npm, gulp, del

**Here is my package.json file:**

```js
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rateb Habedy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp4-run-sequence": "^0.3.1",
    "imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^6.0.j0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "del": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

I just trying to install (**npm - del**) package by this command: `npm install del --save`  after that I'm not able to install any package.

**It says:**

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^6.0.j0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lion/.npm/_logs/2019-03-05T13_49_41_065Z-debug.log
```

Is there any solution for that??

Comment: There is very likely a problem with your package.json file.  

Can you include it in your question, please?

Comment: This is why you don't edit package.json by hand. Just to take a wild guess: vim cursor movement in insert mode?

Comment: ok I include package.json check it please. @Meg

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean @JaredSmith

Comment: @ratebcrypto no worries. I actually make that mistake in my files from time to time because I use vim: in the vim text editor you have various modes only one of which lets you actually insert characters into the file. In one of the other modes `hjkl` move the cursor, so I frequently wind up with those characters at random places when I meant to actually navigate the document. Just delete that j in the version range, it will probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is not with npm del package, but an error, really just a typo, in your package.json file.

See the line:

```
"imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^6.0.j0",
```

That is not a valid version tag, and is not able to be resolved.  You probably want that line to read:

```
"imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^6.0.0",
```

Once you edit that line your npm install should work correctly.

Comment: 'j' maybe typed by mistake